# Linux: Move a batch of files and rename?

Tags: bash, rename, mv

I'm currently trying to move and rename a batch of files. The following `for` loop moves the .jpeg files into each subject's folder (`subjects.txt` is just a text file containing a column of IDs):

```
for i in `awk '{print $1}' data/subjects.txt`; do find data/ -name ${i}\*_img.jpeg | xargs -I file cp file data/${i}/ ; done
```

However, renaming each file to "img.jpeg" hasn't worked so far:

```
for i in `awk '{print $1}' data/subjects.txt`; do find data/ -name ${i}\*_img.jpeg | xargs -I file cp file data/${i}/img.jpeg ; done
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions!

I would like to achieve the following:

```
data/subject_1/img.jpeg
data/subject_2/img.jpeg
data/subject_3/img.jpeg
```

Comment: When yu want to see what `xargs` is trying to do, change `cp` into `echo cp`. After debugging without the `xargs`  command first, see what `find` finds.

Comment: When you don't want to combine `find data -name \*img.jpeg` with `subjects.txt` in one `awk`, change the order so you call `find` once.